# PHP - saber em qual form foi pressionado

Tags: php

Preciso saber qual form foi pressionado.

Estou usando um sistema com get para diferenciar, porem o link ficaria muito sujo.

Meu código:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","escritor");

    if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pagina")){
        if($result->num_rows == 0){
            printf("Não existe nenhuma pagina");
        }else{
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ // pega as informações da linha

                // variavel dos seguidores
                $seguidores = $row["seguidores"]; // ids das pessoas que seguem a pagina
                $array = explode(',', $seguidores); // faz um explode na $seguidores
                if(in_array($userID, $array)){ // verifica se tem o id do usuario no $array
                    $btnValue = "Descurtir"; // coloca o valor do botão como Descurtir
                }else{
                    $btnValue = "Curtir"; // coloca o valor do botão como Curtir
                }
                $link = "?post=".$row['id'];
                printf("<div><form method='post' action='$link'><p>pagina-> <b>".$row['nomePagina']."</b></p> <p>descricao-> <b>".$row["descricao"]."</b></p></label><button name='btnCurtir'>".$btnValue."</button><p></p></form></div>");
            }
        }
    }
```

E usaria

```
   if(isset($_POST['btnCurtir'])){
        $postID = $_GET['post'];    // ai ia aplicar o like no post com o id $postID 
    }
```

Como posso saber em qual form o botão foi pressionado para aplicar o sistema de like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta criar um campo HIDDEN para saber o POST certo, e usar o mesmo nome nos dois botões:

```
 printf("
    <div>
       <form method='post' action='$link'>
          <p>pagina-> <b>".$row['nomePagina']."</b></p>
          <p>descricao-> <b>".$row['descricao']."</b></p>

          <input type='submit' name='botao' value='Curtir'>
          <input type='submit' name='botao' value='Descurtir'>

          <input type='hidden' name='post_id' value='".$row['id']."'>
       </form>
   </div>
");
```

E captura com:

```
$postID = $_POST['post_id'];
$botao  = $_POST['botao'];
```

(ou o nome que quiser no campo, basta adequar o `name` do `input`)

Note que eu troquei o BUTTON por INPUT, pra simplificar. O importante é entender a idéia, e adaptar ao seu caso. Tirei um `</label>` que estava sobrando no código também, dê uma revisada depois. As quebras de linha foram para facilitar a leitura.

**Nota:**

Se o `POST` for para a mesma página, é desnecessário o `action="destino"` no `<form>`, bastando:

```
<form method='post'>
```

Comment: Excelente amigo!